# Library for Manipulating S-Record and Intel HEX 16 Files

Tags: java, python, file, binaryfiles

Is there an available open source library, developed in python or java, for manipulating Motorola S-Record files and Intel HEX 16 files (e.g. converting from one format to the other)?

I am looking for a 'pure' java or python library, not simply a set of java or python bindings to a library like [SRecord](http://srecord.sourceforge.net/).

Answer (score 2):

http://www.bialix.com/intelhex/
for intel hex, I'm not aware of srec python implementations

Answer (score 0):

For Python you can use [bincopy](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/bincopy/1.1.2).  It isn't nearly as feature rich as SRecord, but it is better than nothing!